# Problems when pandas reading Excel file that has blank top row and left column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried to read an Excel file that looks like below, 
[image]

I was using pandas like this

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)
assets = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", header=1, index_col=1)
```

But I got error

> ValueError: Expected 4 fields in line 3, saw 5

I also tried

```
assets = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", header=1, index_col=1, parse_cols="B:E")
```

But I got misparsed result as follows

[image]

Then tried

```
assets = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", header=1, index_col=0, parse_cols="B:E")
```

Finally works, but why index_col=0 and parse_cols="B:E"? This makes me confused becasue based on pandas [documents](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), `assets = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", header=1, index_col=1)` should just be fine. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read_excel` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) is not clear on a point.

- `skiprows=1` to skip the first empty row at the top of the file or `header=1` also works to use the second row has column index.
- `parse_cols='B:E'` is a way to skip the first empty column at the left of the file
- `index_col=0` is optional and permits to define the first parsed column (B in this example) as the `DataFrame` index. The mistake is here since `index_col` is relative to columns selected though the `parse_cols` parameter.

With your example, you can use the following code

```
pd.read_excel('test.xls', sheetname='Sheet1', skiprows=1, 
              parse_cols='B:E', index_col=0)

#           AA  BB  CC
# 10/13/16   1  12  -1
# 10/14/16   3  12  -2
# 10/15/16   5  12  -3
# 10/16/16   3  12  -4
# 10/17/16   5  23  -5
```